# Error in passing data from android application to php server

Tags: php, android, json

I am creating an application which first retrieves data from the php server and displays it in form of tablelayout. Also i have added a button next to each row of tablelayout and once the user presses the button, the entire data of that row is then send to the server.

here is my code of the button

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //  startActivity(f1);

        try {
            Addtocart();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    void Addtocart(){
        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.6/test/cart.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_code",q.getproduct_code().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shaps",q.getShapes().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pair",q.getpair().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carats",q.getCarats().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("color",q.getColor().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clarity",q.getClarity().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service",q.getService().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("polish",q.getPolish().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("symetric",q.getSymetric().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tables",q.getTables().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("measurments",q.getMeasurements().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flourscne",q.getFlourscne().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description",q.getDescription().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("certificated",q.getCerticated().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ccode",q.getCcode().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cut",q.getCut().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total",q.getTotal().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file",q.getFile().toString().trim()));// $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("add to cart")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Availability.this, "Add to cart successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

               // startActivity(new Intent(Availability.this, LoginScreen.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        Availability.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Availability.this);
                builder.setTitle("Can't add to cart.");
                builder.setMessage("Problem in adding to cart. Please try again later")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

here is my error code from the logcat

```
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.diamond.traders.Availability.Addtocart(Availability.java:718)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.diamond.traders.Availability.onClick(Availability.java:652)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 11:26:54.521  17918-17918/com.diamond.traders W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

and here is my entire code
[Availability](http://pastebin.com/Ki5A2DfG)

Answer (score 0):

- You have not mentioned Type of ERROR but as the error is on Line
  number 718 at Availability class i.e on dialog.dismiss(); that might
  be because of NULL pointer exception so before calling this check if
  your dialog is on Showing state.
- implement

  if(dialog.isShowing()){
  dialog.dismiss();
  }
- check if your dialog is initialized or not

  if(dialog!=null){
  //your code inside it
  }